# Max how many Mac Filtering Allowed?

Tags: router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, broadband

I am using a TP-Link TL-WR740N Router. For my business purpose, I only want to give access of Internet to the specific people who are only my Customers (many in numbers).

Now, my Question is, what is the maximum number of Mac-Filtering are allowed from a single Router? And does it vary from Model to Model?

Thanks.

Comment: You do understand its absolutely trivial to mask or change the MAC address, and MAC address filtering must be broadcasted in the open, so anyone that has the knowledge to do so can mask themselves as a client that will connect right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many low-end routers can only manage 256 MAC addresses in their filters, but it's pointless, anyway.

Best method so far is to set up a RADIUS server (freeradius or other) and give each user a password that only applies to that user. MAC address filtering is a laughably bad method.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on model, you need to consult manual.

Mac filtering is not a best way to filter since it can be spoofed. It is better to have separate BSS (WiFi network) and do not give key to people who shall not access Inet